# Stripping an entity from XML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a simple XML workflow which I need to convert to HTML, but the XML contains one or more entities that I'd like to strip out. For example, the original XML contains bullet entities `&#8226;`

I want to replace or delete the actual bullets with HTML bullets using `<ul><li>`elements instead.

Here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="RULEBOOK"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., '&#8226;    ')]">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '&#8226;    ')"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="bullets">
<li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
<ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RULEBOOK>
<SECTION>
<Subsection>
<text>The game of golf should be played in the correct spirit and to understand this you should read the Etiquette Section in the Rules of Golf. In particular: </text>
<ul>
<bullets>&#8226;    show consideration to other players </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    play at a good pace and be ready to invite faster moving groups to play through, and </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    take care of the course by smoothing bunkers, replacing divots and repairing ball marks on the greens. </bullets>
</ul>
<text>Before starting your round you are advised to: </text>
<ul>
<bullets>&#8226;    read the Local Rules on the score card and the notice board </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    put an identification mark on your ball; many golfers play the same brand of ball and if you can&#8217;t identify your ball, it is considered lost (Rules <a>12-2</a> and <a>27-1</a>) </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    count your clubs; you are allowed a maximum of 14 clubs (Rule <a>4-4</a>).
</bullets>
</ul>
<text>During the round: </text>
<ul>
<bullets>&#8226;    don&#8217;t ask for advice from anyone except your partner (i.e., a player on your side) or your caddies; don&#8217;t give advice to anyone except your partner; you may ask for information on the Rules, distances and the position of hazards, the flagstick, etc. (Rule <a>8-1</a>) </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    don&#8217;t play any practice shots during play of a hole (Rule <a>7-2</a>) </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    don&#8217;t use any artificial devices or unusual equipment, unless specifically authorized by Local Rule (Rule <a>14-3</a>). </bullets>
</ul>
<text>At the end of your round:  </text>
<ul>
<bullets>&#8226;    in match play, ensure the result of the match is posted </bullets>
<bullets>&#8226;    in stroke play, ensure that your score card is completed properly (including being signed by you and your marker) and return it to the Committee as soon as possible (Rule <a>6-6</a>). </bullets>
</ul>
</Subsection>
</SECTION></RULEBOOK>
```

Comment: You actually just need to *remove* the `&#8226;    ` characters, right? Since you already have bullets from the `<li>` tag.

Comment: Note: That's a Numeric Character Reference, not an Entity Reference. As far as XML tools are concerned, it just becomes the referenced Unicode character, and you process it as such. Also note that the data model used by XPath and XSLT 1.0 doesn't have the concept of entity references; they're always fully expanded before XSLT sees the document.

Comment: Yes, I want to "remove" the `&#8226;`. If not, I end up with TWO bullets after processing the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., '&#8226;    ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '&#8226;    ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which will find any text node that starts with the bullet and spaces, and preserve only the substring after it.

@keshlam suggested a solution using , which is better since it doesn't depend on spaces or fail if there are any characters before the bullet (but it will remove bullets anywhere in the text, not just at the start):

```
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '&#8226;')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#8226;',''))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The `normalize-space()` function will trim your text removing the extra spaces or tabs.

This works in XSLT 1.0 processors such as Xalan or Saxon 6.

**UPDATE**

Here is a full stylesheet (actually the same one you posted, with the last template above included):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RULEBOOK"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '&#8226;')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#8226;',''))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bullets">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works with your source, when it is copied from the page and pasted in a new file. If it doesn't work in your original file which has the exact same contents, it may be that your original file has a different encoding.

Comment: Alternatively, using `text[contains('&#8226')]` and `select="translate(.,'&#8226','')` would find all instances of the bullet character and just remove that. Or other things could be done, depending on exactly what your needs are.

Comment: That would be a good answer too. Add `normalize-space(...)` to clean up the extra spaces.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this within the existing template matching `bullets` (without requiring a predicate)?

Comment: You could, but it calls `apply-templates` which allows further processing of the node's children. They might not always be text nodes.

Comment: The above answer does NOT remove the numeric character reference. When I process the XML I still end up with `&bull; and an HTML bullet.

If I try `text[contains('&#8226')]` and `select="translate(.,'&#8226','')` it throws an error "The function 'contains()' requires two arguments.Source tree node: text." BTW, I need to use XSLT 1.0 in my workflow. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jim. It works with the code that you posted in your question. Copy the code you posted and paste it here: http://www.xslfiddle.net/ and then add the template to see the result. Since the template I posted tries to remove bullets *and* spaces, it may have failed if 1) your text doesn't really start with the character followed by 4 spaces, or 2) if there are more or less spaces after the bullet, if it's actually a tab, etc. I will add to the answer the solution proposed by @keshlam.

Comment: OK. I will do that momentarily. As for how I did it I copied the entity from the XML to the XSLT so it would match. Will it work if the space is actually a tab? I believe it is.

Comment: It works on the XML I posted. But it still does not work on the actual source. But it may be an XPath problem. I simplified the XML in the example. I'm updating the XML to match the source exactly. Please review the source data to see if the XSLT needs a tweak. Thanks

Comment: The second template doesn't care about tabs or spaces. For the first one you can test for tabs *or* spaces using `text()[starts-with(., '&#8226;    ') or starts-with(., '&#8226;&#09;')]`.

Comment: You could also use `normalize-space()` to trim, and eliminate whitespace matching in the first template: `normalize-space(substring-after(., '&#8226;'))`

Comment: OK, now the XML doesn't convert using the template. I will try the alternate view.

Comment: I posted the entire workflow now. It doesn't work, but I may have used something incorrectly.

Comment: It's missing the closing tag `</xsl:stylesheet>`.

Comment: It was in the file I just missed it on the example. Sorry. I've added it to the example, but it still gives me two bullets.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce your problem. If you copy the code you posted and paste it in the online XSLT service I linked above, you will see that it works. If it doesn't work in your original code, it may be an encoding problem (some hidden or different character that will not match).

Comment: The alternate XSLT you posted worked perfectly. It results in clean HTML. Great. Thanks